# strings containing special hexadecimal to convert

Tags: javascript, php, character-encoding

hello how to convert strings containing %C3%A0 codes etc ... 
in normal characters
received from PHP to be handled by JavaScript and after by shell in a simple way

thank you by advance

Comment: Could you please post your full input and the output that you want here?

Comment: you reply to me wrong mister barmar and i dont know how to contest your decision , sorry for my english i a french